# Prove that $f = (f_1,\ldots,f_d)$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers

Let $(S,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space. For each $j\in\{1,\dots,d\}$ let $f_j:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.

**Exercise:** Prove that the function $f:S\to\mathbb{R}^d$ given by $f = (f_1,\ldots,f_d)$ is a measurable function.

I have this definition of measurability:

> Let $(S,\mathcal{A})$ and $(T,\mathcal{B})$ be two measurable spaces and let $f:S\to T$. Suppose $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$ is such that $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \mathcal{B}$. If $f^{-1}(F) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $F\in\mathcal{F}$ then $f$ is a measurable.

*My approach:* Since I want to use the above definition, I want to look at the half-open rectangles. We know that for all half-open rectangles $I = I_1\times I_2\times\ldots\times I_d \subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ we have that $f^{-1}(I) = \{s\in S:f_j(s)\in I_j\} = f^{-1}_1(I_1) \cap f^{-1}_2(I_2)\cap\ldots \cap f^{-1}_d(I_d)$.

Furthermore, I can prove that $\sigma(\text{half open rectangles}) = \sigma(\mathcal{F^d}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. That means that if I can show that for each $F\in\mathcal{F}$ we have that $f^{-1}(F)\in\mathcal{A}$, we have that $f$ is measurable.

**Question:** How do I show that for each $F\in\mathcal{F}$ we have that $f^{-1}(F)\in\mathcal{A}$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that $f^{-1}(F)\in\mathcal A$ for every $F\in\mathcal F$ have a look at the collection: $$\{S\subseteq\mathbb R^d\mid f^{-1}(S)\in\mathcal A\}$$

It can easily be shown to be a $\sigma$-algebra so if it contains any collection $\mathcal V$ then it will also contain $\sigma(\mathcal V)$.

Apply this on the collection of half-open rectangles.